# Bundle a set of Ruby gems as one RPM

Tags: rubygems, rpm, rpmbuild

I want to take a group of gems and bundle them together as a single RPM. I know gem2rpm and fpm exist, but only work for a single gem

Answer (score 1):

An idea comes to mind:

- build source rpms of each gem with fpm
- unpack the srpms and open the .spec files
- combine the content of each spec into another one